# EF Core SQL logging with parameters in DECLARE format

Tags: logging, parameters, entity-framework-core

When EF Core logs SQL commands with parameters, these parameters appear in a form which is not usable for copy&paste to a SQL Management Studio window for ad hoc querying.

This is as of EF Core 2.2.

When we inspect SQLs from customer logs, we want to rerun them on our customer database to see the result set. For example, EF Core logs something like this:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (60ms) [Parameters=[@__p_4='50', @__value_0='KREUZSTR' (Size = 255) (DbType = AnsiString), @__value_1='4711' (Size = 20) (DbType = AnsiString), @__value_2='City' (Size = 255) (DbType = AnsiString), @__value_3='VonDummy,S.' (Size = 255)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      -- BlCustomerDuplicateRecognition.cs:462 in GenerateSearchQuery

      SELECT TOP(@__p_4) [cust].[primkey], [cust].[c_custno] ...
```

This is not very useful. I have to manually convert the parameters to

```sql
DECLARE @__p_4 INT = 50,
        @__value_0 VARCHAR(255) = 'KREUZSTR',
        @__value_1 VARCHAR(20) = '4711',
        @__value_2 VARCHAR(255) = 'City',
        @__value_3 VARCHAR(255) = 'VonDummy,S.'
SELECT TOP(@__p_4) [cust].[primkey], [cust].[c_custno] ...
```

which is very annoying.
Is there a way to tell EF Core to log the paramater declarations in a way usable for copy&paste for an ad-hoc query?

Comment: Did u find solution ?

Comment: @HaktanEnesBiçer Not yet. Any idea?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution. If there is no tool I think I write one myself.